# Plotting the solution of a differential equation with its derivative

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, interpolation

The question requires checking of numerical solutions to a differential equation by substituting in those solutions.

The original equation is as follows;

```
equ = y'[t] - (t^2 y[t]^2)/(1 + 8 t^4)
```

And the numerical solution for `y[t]` is calculated as;

```
sol = NDSolve[{y'[t] == (t^2 y[t]^2)/(1 + 8 t^4), y[0] == 1/2}, y[t], {t, 0, 1.5}]

sol = {{y[t] -> InterpolatingFunction[{{0., 1.5}}, <>][t]}}
```

I have produced the following pice of code;

```
Plot[Evaluate[equ /. {y[t] -> sol, y'[t] -> D[sol, t]}], {t, 0., 1.5}]
```

But it does not produce a graph (it does output the axes) and there is no error message.

If anyone can fix my code, or suggest a better method of substituting in the values for the numerical solution of the equation, I would be very grateful.

Comment: Please supply all necessary data/definitons. How do you arrive at `sol`?

Comment: `sol = NDSolve[{y'[t] == (t^2 y[t]^2)/(1 + 8 t^4), y[0] == 1/2}, y, {t, 0, 1.5}]` (`y` instead of `y[t]`.) Then, `Plot[Evaluate[equ /. sol], {t, 0., 1.5}]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best approach to solving the kind of problem you pose it to structure things to produce pure interpolation functions. To do that proceed as follows:

```
yF =
  NDSolve[
    {y'[t] == (t^2 y[t]^2)/(1 + 8 t^4), y[0] == 1/2},
    y, {t, 0, 1.5}][[1, 1, 2]];

dyF = yF'
```

Then you can render the two functions on one plot with

```
Plot[{yF[t], dyF[t]}, {t, 0, 1.5}, AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image: one-plot]

but I don't think this looks good because the ranges of `yF` and `dyF` are so different. Rather I recommend make two plots.

```
Column[
  {Plot[{yF[t]}, {t, 0, 1.5},
     PlotLabel -> y[t], AspectRatio -> 1, ImageSize -> Medium],
   Plot[{dyF[t]}, {t, 0, 1.5},
     PlotLabel -> y'[t], AspectRatio -> 1, ImageSize -> Medium]},
  Spacings -> 1.5]
```

[image: two-plots]

Answer (score 2):

Rather than two separate plots, you may prefer a single plot with two differently scaled $y$-axes. To do so, use the function `TwoAxisPlot`, which is defined on the Documentation Center page `howto/GeneratePlotsWithTwoVerticalScales`.

Using the definitions of `yF` and `dyF` from @m_goldberg's answer:

```
    TwoAxisPlot[{yF[t], dyF[t]}, {t, 0, 1.5}]
```

[image]